# MySQL query for two users with common responses to a survey

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with users who have completed a survey - in some cases, they have complete the survey multiple times. So it looks like this:

users|survey_attempt|question_num|response
---------------------------------------------
john  | 1                             | 1                            | cat
john  | 1                                 | 2                            | dog
john  | 1                                  | 3                            | frog
john  | 2                                  | 1                            | dog
john  | 2                                  | 2                            | frog   
john  | 2                                  | 3                            | dog    
jim     | 1                                  | 1                            | frog   
jim    | 1                                  | 2                            | bat    
jim     | 1                                  | 3                            | bat    
jim    | 2                                  | 1                            | cat    
jim    | 2                                  | 2                            | frog   
jim    | 2                                  | 3                            | bat

In this case, how would I find users who had common responses within the same attempt at the survey? So for instance, if I wanted to know who answered "frog" and "cat" within a unique attempt at the survey (regardless of which specific question the answer was for)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the database layout has flaws. I would suggest to use unique survey submission IDs. Because right now, you need to check user name AND survey attempt to determine if two or more rows belong to the same submission.

Anyways, you would need to self join the table and check for the answer you want but disregard the question:

```
SELECT A.users, A.survey_attempt
FROM table A
  INNER JOIN table B ON A.users = B.users AND A.survey_attempt = B.survey_attempt
WHERE A.response = 'frog'
  AND B.response = 'cat';
```

The table is matched with itself, in each result table you'll have all columns two times. Then the query will only select these rows where both user names and survey attempt numbers are equal. Finally, the WHERE statement checks for the answers you wanted. Nowhere, the question number is checked as you wanted to get the result regardless of specific questions.